# Genymotion ARM Translation failed for Android 7 above

Tags: android, arm, genymotion, android-8.0-oreo

I tried to install ARM Translation on my Genymotion emulator which runs Android 7 above. But it failed with below error message:

> Genymotion failed to flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip archieve for an unknown reason. Some details might be found in the logcat file of the virtual device.

I tried below ARM translation (these all I can found):

1. Genymotion-ARM-Translation_for_amd_phenom
2. Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1

Both giving the same error. 
Anyone know where to get correct ARM translation for Android 7 above?

I found this error on the logcat during the process:

```
05-16 08:36:20.159: I/flash-archive.sh(2879): [sanitize_zipfile_and_execute_update_binary] Repackaging system/lib/arm/libutils.so ARM lib
05-16 08:36:20.185: I/flash-archive.sh(2885): [sanitize_zipfile_and_execute_update_binary] Repackaging system/lib/arm/libvorbisidec.so ARM lib
05-16 08:36:20.209: I/flash-archive.sh(2891): [sanitize_zipfile_and_execute_update_binary] Repackaging system/lib/arm/libwpa_client.so ARM lib
05-16 08:36:20.235: I/flash-archive.sh(2897): [sanitize_zipfile_and_execute_update_binary] Repackaging system/lib/arm/libz.so ARM lib
05-16 08:36:22.134: I/updater(2902): line 3 col 36: unknown function "delete_recursive"
05-16 08:36:22.134: I/updater(2902): 1 parse errors
05-16 08:36:22.134: I/updater(2902): updater terminated by exit(6)
05-16 08:36:22.139: E/flash-archive.sh(2904): [execute_update_binary] execution of update-binary ended with errors
05-16 08:36:22.144: E/flash-archive.sh(2905): {Result:KO};
```

Comment: Can you share the urls for the ARM translation packages you are using?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ud84PblsmrU-ifjo9jJeGI0LTa1K5Vlm
and
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xaQ7QRfyrOtTGsHT80-dXwsiybMvJVaF

Comment: @noobsee did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @anjujo nope, i didn't find anything in the end

Answer (score -2):

Please install genymotion arm translation from the link blow:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation/master/package/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_for_8.0.zip